Add post content to WooCommerce email
I am using a theme for tours booking, the theme uses a core plugin which can add the tours i independent tab. after posting the tour and view it, there is a button "Book Now" for each tour when this button is clicked the tour title, price, quantity and booking date added and displayed on cart. after proceeding to checkout and fills the user details "place order" button is clicked to send order.
An email is sent through customer-processing-email.php to the customer showing the order details, now am trying to add the other tour information like (highlights, includes and excludes, itinerary). but since am a beginner in WooCommerce and WordPress development am not sure how i can access the tour and reach its fields and send them with the email.
lets say i want to send the highlights which is defined in "tours.php" as:
CSF::createSection(
    "EGNS_TOURS_META_ID",
    array(
        'parent' => 'tours_highlights_meta_option',
        'title'  => esc_html__('Tour Highlights', 'triprex-core'),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'type'    => 'subheading',
                'content' => esc_html__('Highlights Of Tour', 'triprex-core'),
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'tours_highlights_title',
                'type'    => 'text',
                'title'   => esc_html__('Heading Title', 'triprex-core'),
                'default' => 'Highlights of the Tour',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => 'tours_highlights_title_list',
                'type'  => 'textarea',
                'title' => esc_html__('Content', 'triprex-core'),
                'desc'  => 'Enter A List Of Highlights Separated By <mark>Line Breaks</mark>',
            ),
        ),
    )
); 

how can i use the functions.php and the customer-processing-email.php template to add this field there ?
i tried to use hooks in functions.php to modify the email content but didn't work:
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_tour_highlights_to_email', 10, 3);
function add_tour_highlights_to_email($order_id, $sent_to_admin, $order) {
   
    $tour_highlight = Egns\Helper\Egns_Helper::egns_tours_value('tours_highlights_title_list');
if ($tour_highlight) {
    $tour_highlight_list = explode("\n", $tour_highlight);
    
    echo '<h2>Tour Highlights</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($tour_highlight_list as $item) {
        $trimmed_item = trim($item);
        if (!empty($trimmed_item)) {
            echo '<li>' . esc_html($trimmed_item) . '</li>';
        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
}

Thank you.

I recently needed to do this. Here's a modified version of your code that should work.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'add_tour_highlights_to_email', 10, 3 );
function add_tour_highlights_to_email( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
 
  $tour_highlight = Egns\Helper\Egns_Helper::egns_tours_value('tours_highlights_title_list');

  if ($tour_highlight) {
    $tour_highlight_list = explode("\n", $tour_highlight);

    $highlights = '<ul>';

    foreach ($tour_highlight_list as $item) {
      $trimmed_item = trim($item);
      if (!empty($trimmed_item)) {
          $highlights .= '<li>' . esc_html($trimmed_item) . '</li>';
      }
    }

    $highlights .= '</ul>';

    $fields['tour_highlights'] = array(
      'label' => __( 'Tour Highlights', 'add_extra_fields' ),
      'value' => $highlights,
    );
  }
}

